# Family sharing - Why do i still need to pay?

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

Me and my brother are having some trouble with the steam family sharing function, we wanted to split our account because we want to play our own games at the same time, but when we were younger we made an account together so that we didn't have to pay two times for the games that we both wanted to play. 
When my brother made his own account, he could play all our and his own games but H1Z1 with told him to pay again, Why is it so? and how do we solve it?
(H1Z1, is his game and not mine which means I'm not interested in playing it, and he payed it himself)

Comment: Because that's the way Valve set it up.

Answer (score 8):

Only one person can access the shared library at a time.

The [FAQ clearly states it](http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing):

> **Can two users share a library and both play at the same time?**
>
> No, a shared library may only be accessed by one user at a time.

Comment: Steam family sharing works great for families who use their accounts on the same computer... not so great for families who use their accounts on *different* computers.

Answer (score 0):

Well the family sharing feature is focused on the library being in use by only 1 person at any given time. now if you both have different accounts and different computers and on account is sharing with another there is a workaround.

If one goes into a game and then goes offline, the other user can still use the library since it registers that the library is no longer in use. An obvious thing to point out is that this wont work with games that require you to be online(purely multiplayer and such)